# How to make 'before' blocks specific to shared examples only?

Tags: ruby, rspec

Consider the following spec `test.rb`:

```
describe 'Thing' do

    shared_examples 'becomes_sad' do

            before(:all) do
                    puts 'Begin becomes_sad'
            end

            after(:all) do
                    puts 'Finalize becomes_sad'
            end

            it 'shared test #1' do; end
            it 'shared test #2' do; end

    end

    shared_examples 'becomes_happy' do

            before(:all) do
                    puts 'Begin becomes_happy'
            end

            after(:all) do
                    puts 'Finalize becomes_happy'
            end

            it 'shared test #3' do; end
    end

    include_examples 'becomes_sad'
    include_examples 'becomes_happy'

end
```

When I run `rspec --format documentation test.rb`, I receive:

```
Thing
  Begin becomes_sad
  Begin becomes_happy
    shared test #1
    shared test #2
    shared test #3
  Finalize becomes_happy
  Finalize becomes_sad
```

What I expected and need is the following:

```
Thing
  Begin becomes_sad
    shared test #1
    shared test #2
  Finalize becomes_sad
  Begin becomes_happy
    shared test #3
  Finalize becomes_happy
```

How do I do this? RSpec version is 2.99.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is,  both of the `before(:all)` blocks will be added to the same example group/context. Because things like `before` hooks apply to an example group as a whole,  if you want different behaviour then you need to create different example groups.

You'd have to do something along the lines of

```
context 'sad' do
  include_examples 'becomes_sad'
end

context 'happy' do
  include_examples 'becomes_happy'
end
```